# When do two RuntimeMethodHandles from different MethodInfos compare as equal?

Tags: .net, reflection

When I have two different `MethodInfo` objects, it's possible that their `MethodHandle` values still compare equal. This can happen when obtaining the method handle of a non-generic method of two different instantiations of the same generic type, but not always. Experimentally, I can determine that it isn't the case with static methods, nor when one of the instantiations is with a value type.

```
using System;

static class Program
{
  static void Main()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Foo<object>.f == Foo<string>.f: " +
      (typeof(Foo<object>).GetMethod("f").MethodHandle ==
       typeof(Foo<string>).GetMethod("f").MethodHandle));
    Console.WriteLine("Foo<object>.f == Foo<int>.f: " +
      (typeof(Foo<object>).GetMethod("f").MethodHandle ==
       typeof(Foo<int>).GetMethod("f").MethodHandle));
    Console.WriteLine("Foo<object>.g == Foo<string>.g: " +
      (typeof(Foo<object>).GetMethod("g").MethodHandle ==
       typeof(Foo<string>).GetMethod("g").MethodHandle));
    Console.WriteLine("Foo<object>.g == Foo<int>.g: " +
      (typeof(Foo<object>).GetMethod("g").MethodHandle ==
       typeof(Foo<int>).GetMethod("g").MethodHandle));
    Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class Foo<T>
{
  public void f() { }
  public static void g() { }
}
```

Output:

```
Foo<object>.f == Foo<string>.f: True
Foo<object>.f == Foo<int>.f: False
Foo<object>.g == Foo<string>.g: False
Foo<object>.g == Foo<int>.g: False
```

However, I'm not able to find any official documentation on this. Are there any guarantees for the results I'm getting? Which of these results can I safely assume will not change in future updates of .NET Framework, and which might?

I'm asking specifically because I have code that relies on `Foo<object>.f` and `Foo<string>.f` having the same method handle (in code that needs to check whether a `MethodInfo` is `Foo<T>.f` for some `T`, where `T` is known to be a reference type), and I want to know if I need to rewrite that code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a clear definition for the semantics of `RuntimeMethodHandle`. However, you should be able to use [`MethodInfo.MetadataToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.metadatatoken.aspx) instead, provided the `MethodInfo` is in the same module as `Foo<object>.f` (different modules can share metadata token values, but the same metadata token only has one meaning within a particular module). If the `MethodInfo` comes from an arbitrary location, first check the [`Module`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.module.aspx) property for equality and then check the `MetadataToken` property.

Comment: The `MethodInfo` is not known to represent a method from any particular assembly, but checking the declaring type's assembly (or alternatively, the `MethodInfo`'s `Module` property) in addition to `MetadataToken` seems like a very workable alternative, thanks. If no one answers with a guarantee that the `MethodHandle` approach is reliable, I'll likely go with that.